# Find specific question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, search

Just one or two days ago there was a question about real world applications of graph theory on SO (the main Stack Overflow site) listed in hot network questions. Now I cannot find it. Do you know how or where it can be found or if there is some better way than searching here in via Google to find it? I did visit the question using the SO Android app so maybe I have some history with it.

Comment: You sure it wasn't this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126198/what-are-some-real-world-applications-of-graphs ?

Comment: @oguzismail That's it :-) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of chat rooms that have a feed that posts all Hot Network Questions. So basically if a question had been on the HNQ list it is for example [listed in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=real&room=89485) (assuming my [app on Glitch](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/) didn't break or had an outage). Some sites have a chatroom with [an HNQ feed for only their site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108263/hot-network-questions). That might make looking for a question easier if you remember the site but not the title.

Alternatively you could leverage [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324663/158100) but SEDE only updates once a week so that might not be that handy if you want to go back only a couple of days back.